# Sort JSON Data from HTTP request with a function before putting it in Firestore

Tags: firebase, sorting, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need a function that receives information from an HTTPS request and then puts the data in specific collections/documents based on what the data is.

To simplify, If I recieve a JSON with the data "Color: blue" I want to put it in document 1. But if I get "Color: green" I want to put it in document 2.

[EDIT] So say I have collection users and 2 documents in that collection, DOC1 and DOC2. Do I put a switch statement somewhere or how do I sort the data so the function knows where to place it.

This is not exactly what I want to do but it is the same concept. I need to put the data in specific documents based on the JSON file I receive.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. I have been stuck on this for a few days now.

I have watched videos and looked at googles documentation but I am very new to functions and do not really understand. The function I am using right now just accepts data and puts it in a specific spot. I also had help making it so I am don't even truly understand it either.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const _ = require('lodash');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
let data = req.query.data;

try {
      await db.collection('users').doc().set({ userId: data });
    } catch(err) { res.send(JSON.stringify(err)) }

  res.send('Success');
})

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  let payload = req.body;
  let keys = Object.keys(payload);
  let obj = {};
  let i = 0;

  try {
    _.forEach(payload, async data => {
      obj[keys[i]] = data;
      i++;
    })
    //

  await db.collection('users').doc().set(obj);
  } catch(err) { res.send(JSON.stringify(err))}

      res.send('Success');
    })

    exports.writeToFirestore = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

This is my current function that just accepts JSON data and puts it all in 
  the same spot.

Comment: You're not specifying a document id in `doc` so it's just going to the users collection. When you read your data, figure out what doc id it should go to and pass that to `doc()`.

Comment: Can you update the question with the documents you wish to add the data to? E.g. do you know the document IDs of where the data should end up? What do you know about the correlation between the data you receive and the final document?

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought I was doing with the color example. So if I receive a json packet with color: blue I want it to go to doc1 and if color: green I want to put it in doc2. This is just a basic example so someone could show me how and then I would apply it to my actual needs. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Am I supposed to have a switch statement somewhere? If so where would I put it. I am just looking for a super basic example to go off of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's give an answer with a simple HTTPS Cloud Function, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#trigger_a_function_with_an_http_request).

Let's imagine you pass the color as a URL QueryString param (see http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.

```
exports.switchWrite = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const color = req.params.color;

  let firestoreDocumentId;
  if (color === 'blue') {
     firestoreDocumentId = 'DOC1'
  } else {
     //Then color is green!! Up to you to make a more complex "switch"
     firestoreDocumentId = 'DOC2'
  }

    const db = admin.firestore();
    db.collection('collectionId').doc(firestoreDocumentId)
    .set({
        foo: bar
    })
    .then(() => {
       res.status(200).send({status: 'saved', color: color});  //For example
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
       res.status(500).send(error);
    })

});
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks! Would there be a big difference if I was to receive a json with many objects inside and then base the switch off of a single object. E.g.  { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null } and sort it by the name?

Comment: I don't think there will be a big difference. On one hand you have the switch that defines the Document ID and on the other hand you write to the document corresponding to the Document ID. The switch can be as complex as you want! You can receive the JSON in the body of the request, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request